# Auto-detect new controllers to add actions to menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails 3 application that will have an admin area with a side menu (similar to the Wordpress admin menu.)

I was wondering what the best method would be to have rails automatically detect when a new controller is added to the admin and add the appropriate actions to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Anything about 'Admin' needs to be done? It's best that you use [Active Admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin)

It will take care of your problem too. I would highly recommend that you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of controllers with this code:

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route| route.defaults[:controller] end
```

Inspect the output, as it will give you duplicate results, filter them and you can use it.

As a side note: are you sure you want all controllers in your admin interface? It makes no sense, maybe you should try Active Admin, has suggested earlier.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, I was thinking when I was initially considering this that I would have some way of only including the actions that I wanted in the side menu, perhaps using a before filter. If no actions were included then no entry would be created for the controller. But as you say, I wasn't aware of Active Admin when I posted the question, I'll give it some attention.